# React-Navigation Rest and unmount previous components

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the react-navigation to do the navigation part in the My App. But got some problem when trying to fulfill this function:

Now I got some screens in stack of StackNavigator:

[Main]

[Login]

[Wizard A]

[Wizard B]

After user finish the job at [Wizard B] page, the App should navigate to [Welcome] page and the previous pages should be unmounted.

I've tried to do this at my [Wizard B] container:

```
ownProps.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Welcome', params: {...} }),
    ],
  }));
```

But it seems that the previous pages are not unmounted.
Can anyone share any walkaround to force to unmount the page in the stack? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The ugly walkaround is pop all other screens out of stack and push [Welcome]....

Comment: the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086021/react-navigation-make-component-keep-re-rendering-when-navigate-to-other-screen might help